# How do I convert a list to local storage and convert back to the same variable?

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

```
    let grid = [];
    function redirect()
    {
        localStorage.setItem("newGrids", JSON.stringify(grid));
        window.location.href = 'easterEgg.html';
    }
    
    function makeTable()
    {
        if (localStorage.newGrids) 
        {
            var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("newGrids");
            grid = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
        {
        else 
       {
            for (let row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
            {
               let temp = [];
               for (let col = 0; col < numCols; col++)
            {
               temp.push(new GuessCell('-'));
            }
               grid.push(temp);
           }   
      }
```

Here is the code. I want to assign the value of "grid" to "newGrids"(in local storage) when the code goes to a new page and then put the value back into "grid" when the page loads again. The code is not saving the grid when run.

Comment: There's no reason for it not to work. Check Developer Tools to make sure the data is getting into localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

This line feels odd in the code. You can't use the localStorage object like this.

if (localStorage.newGrids)

Other than that the code looks fine. Unless the rows are not having any data, the grid value would have stored.

Comment: You can refer to keys in localStorage by using the key name with dot syntax. See [Basic Concepts under MDN's documentation of the Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#basic_concepts).